# Factoring terms-laws of exponents

Tags: factoring

Given the exponent terms $x^m+x^{2m}$, how would it look like if we factor out $x^m$?

Comment: Hint: $x^{pq} = (x^{p})^q$

Answer (score 2):

Factoring something out is essentially just dividing each term by the same thing and then bringing it out. Basically the distribution property in reverse.

If you were to do your problem step by step it would look something like this:

$\ x^m + x^{2m} = x^m ({x^m\over x^m}+{x^{2m}\over x^m})=x^m(1+x^{2m-m})=x^m(1+x^m)$